# why is it grammatically incorrect to say "very incredible"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, descriptive-grammar, gradability

I have been told that it is wrong to say "very incredible " and "very fantastic". Could you tell me why?

Comment: It isn't "wrong". Any adjective can basically be preceded by very, except for unique. Some thing that is unique is unique. Ergo, very unique sounds like one doesn't know the basic meaning of unique.

Comment: Unique isn't unique in this way: pregnant, dead, anything that is discrete instead of continuous.  "Incredible" wouldn't be on that list.  But using "very" is not creative and is not specific, so for some styles of writing, is not welcome. It's clearly understandable, though.

Comment: What has your *own research* shown, lucy? At the top right of this page, there is a small "help v" button. Please click on it and take the "Tour." It will give you a better idea of what is expected of questions here. Welcome to EL&U!

Comment: Also, the question will be improved by quoting specific examples (with context /surrounding text/source) of "very incredible" and "very fantastic" that you are concerned about.

Comment: Incredible, can mean that something was exceptionally good e.g. A: *How was the food?* B: *It was incredible*, or *It was incredibly good* To say something was *very incredible*, could be ambiguous. Not wrong, but confusing or redundant. Things can also be "incredibly bad" ( = very incredible)

Comment: @Mark Hubbard Oeuf corse, but who is talking about editing manuscripts? Grammatically, it isn't wrong to say: very incredible even if it sounds somewhat idiotic. I don't see how very fantastic is ***grammatically*** incorrect.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree and said so in my comment, edited for brevity below.

Comment: As we write we tend to get excited about our topic and insert "very" in many places where it is simply unnecessary. It's not that claiming your subject is "very fantastic" is grammatically incorrect, but it is stylistically "over the top." This becomes clear if you exaggerate it further by saying something like, "That new movie I just watched is very, very, very incredible!"

Comment: @Mark Hubbard Whoops, sorry I misread. NOT saying.

Comment: Just use ***truly*** instead.  You’ll achieve the very emphasis you were going for in a very much more standard way.

Comment: It is certainly possible for something to be "a little incredible", taking "incredible" with its literal meaning.  "Incredible" means "not believable", and it certainly is possible that some small part of a statement would not be believable while other parts would be.  "Very incredible" simply means that quite a lot having to do with the matter at hand cannot be believed.

Answer (score 5):

There are certain adjectives, called absolute adjectives, which *allegedly* should not be modified, because *logically* ( but not grammatically) there is no way to modify them. Logically, you can't be be very dead, very pregnant or very unique. I can give you a *perfectly* logical argument (and I admit that an argument is either logical or it's not) that our founding fathers couldn't form a *more perfect* union, and that you cannot be *more specific* because you either specify something or you don't. English is beautiful, but not logical, so that the answer to the question is that when you modify an absolute adjective, you should know that those of a logical bent will fuss. I won't agree with them not now, not never, not noways. Do not count up the negations to check the parity to see what I mean. Here, https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/very-unique-and-absolute-adjectives, is a defense of might point of view by Merriam Webster.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, it is not grammatically incorrect however saying "very incredible" or "very fantastic" is both redundant and uncreative. The word "very" is not bad but it generally leads to weak writing because it is often used to strengthen a word rather than finding a stronger word.
"He ran very fast" is a weaker way of saying "he sprinted" (Edit: "he ran quickly" is a closer alternative) just like saying "that was very good" is weaker than "that was incredible" or "that was fantastic."

"Incredible" and "fantastic" are already strong words and the use of "very" only serves to weaken their impact.

Comment: Related to Jon Hanna by any chance? I mean that's really an incredible piece of coincidence,

Comment: « "He ran very fast" is a weaker way of saying "he sprinted" » — No. Absolutely not. They mean different things, and one is no ‘weaker’ than the other. This kind of “use stronger words” thing is very Strunk-and-Whiteish, and it's terrible advice. Or very bad advice, if you will. It dumbs down language and removes creativity from its usage.

Comment: Perhaps it is a little hardline. I am, by no means, saying to boycott all instances of "weaker words" because they are equally necessary to the English language and our culture. I am, however, saying not to use "very" and other strengthening words as a crutch. Many people allow these to take over their writing rather than putting forth the effort to find a better word. That is not to say that you should never use "he ran very fast." I will edit the above post so that the alternative is "he ran quickly" rather than "he sprinted." Ironically, I too hate the trope of "remove all the adverbs."

Answer (score 1):

To what extent we'd say "wrong" is debatable, but if something is incredible then it is impossible to believe it. If two things are impossible to believe then one cannot be more impossible than the other; it's an absolute. As an absolute it makes no sense to say something is *very* incredible; it's either incredible or it isn't.

*Fantastic* is similar in that it means something is not related to reality. It's a bit more defensible though to say that one thing is further departing from reality than another.

In figurative use though, it makes perfect sense that something described as *incredible* is more so than something else described as *incredible* since such figurative uses do not literally mean something is impossible to believe.

But in doing something with the word in a figurative use that cannot be done meaningfully with it in a literal use, it moves further from the literal meaning and figurative senses get their force and vitality from evoking the literal meaning.

As such, while it can be defended as a valid figurative use, it has less power that way and generally we use *very* to add force, not reduce it. So even if its not "wrong" as such, it may still be worth cutting out the *very*.

Comment: Incidentally, my take on the figurative use of *literally* that people often complain of as wrong is similar; there's no reason why *literally* can't be used figuratively and if nobody else did it it would be a very forceful and evocative figurative use. It being used so often though has weakened its ability to evoke the literal meaning just as using a word figuratively in a construct that doesn't work with the literal meaning ("very incredible") and so weakened that figurative potential. The result isn't wrong English, it's just not good English.

Comment: Curiously it used to be more common in the past: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+incredible&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20incredible%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Would the down-voter care to comment on how Jon should improve his answer?

Comment: @MarkHubbard I'd be surprised if they do.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I guess things were "very incredible" in 1837. :-)

Comment: @Josh interesting, but not very surprising since figurative uses go through fads and fashions even more than literal uses and since "very incredible" only makes sense with figurative uses we can deduce that most of those uses are figurative and by extension that we'd likely have a spikes for it *somewhere* on the chart.

Comment: I found this interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panic_of_1837 1837 was the beginning of a seven-year recession in the United States. It was hard times for all, apparently, not unlike the 2009 financial crisis for us. ("Everything old is new again.")

Comment: @MarkHubbard at the time a lot of people blamed immigrants for it, though environmental problems affecting the balance of world trade (by causing a poor harvest in the UK, though likely not a human-caused environmental problem) and the actions of large banks had a much bigger impact.

Comment: This answer is not very credible.

Comment: George Washington and Mahatma Gandhi were the "founding fathers" of the USA.  Is that statement completely incredible, or only partly incredible?

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm sure it's completely credible - someone out there would believe it. Probably someone who's never heard of either George Washington or Mahatma Gandhi, but I'm sure there are people like that who exist. They're probably younger than you or me.